# Beautiful soup extracting data from default url not update or provided in code

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am looking to extract table using below URL:

https://www.agmrc.org/fruit-and-vegetable-market-data?StartDate=2018-04-27&EndDate=2021-06-15&page=1&items=50

However, the code posted below provides me with data from default page:

https://www.agmrc.org/fruit-and-vegetable-market-data?StartDate=2021-06-09&EndDate=2021-06-15&page=1&items=25

Using this code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.parse


beg_yr = '2018-04-27'
end_yr = '2021-06-15'
items = 50

URL = 'https://www.agmrc.org/fruit-and-vegetable-market-data?StartDate='+beg_yr+'&EndDate='+end_yr+'&page=1&items='+str(items)

page = requests.post(URL)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'lxml')

table_rows = soup.find("div",{'class':'table w-embed'}).find_all('table',{'class':'content-table'})
lop = 0
l = []
for tr in table_rows:
    td = tr.find_all('td')
    row = [tr.text for tr in td]
    l.append(row)
    print(row)
    lop += 1
    print(lop)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
import httpx
import trio
import pandas as pd


async def main():
    async with httpx.AsyncClient(timeout=None) as client:
        data = {
            'StartDate': '2018-04-27',
            'EndDate': '2021-06-15',
            'page': 1,
            'items': 50
        }
        r = await client.post('https://www.agmrc.org/fruit-and-vegetable-market-data', data=data)
        df = pd.read_html(
            r.text, attrs={'class': 'content-table'}, header=0)[0]
        print(df)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    trio.run(main)
```

Output:

```
    Select        Date    Region   Class     Commodity  Variety Organic  Environment                Unit  Number of Stores  Weighted Avg Price  Low Price  High Price  % Marked Local
0      NaN  04/27/2018  NATIONAL  FRUITS   APPLE PEARS      NaN     NaN          NaN                each               175                1.00        NaN         NaN             NaN
1      NaN  04/27/2018  NATIONAL  FRUITS   APPLE PEARS      NaN     NaN          NaN           per pound                77                1.50        NaN         NaN             NaN
2      NaN  04/27/2018  NATIONAL  FRUITS       BANANAS      NaN     NaN          NaN           per pound              2048                0.44        NaN         NaN             NaN
3      NaN  04/27/2018  NATIONAL  FRUITS       BANANAS      NaN     Yes          NaN           per pound              1373                0.69        NaN         NaN             NaN
4      NaN  04/27/2018  NATIONAL  FRUITS  BLACKBERRIES      NaN     NaN          NaN  5.6 - 6 oz package              5997                2.55        NaN         NaN             NaN
5      NaN  04/27/2018  NATIONAL  FRUITS  BLACKBERRIES      NaN     Yes          NaN  5.6 - 6 oz package              1377                3.45        NaN         NaN             NaN
6      NaN  04/27/2018  NATIONAL  FRUITS   BLUEBERRIES      NaN     NaN          NaN      1 pint package              6106                2.95        NaN         NaN             NaN
7      NaN  04/27/2018  NATIONAL  FRUITS   BLUEBERRIES      NaN     NaN          NaN       18 oz package               555                4.88        NaN         NaN             NaN
8      NaN  04/27/2018  NATIONAL  FRUITS   BLUEBERRIES      NaN     NaN          NaN        6 oz package              4298                2.69        NaN         NaN             NaN
9      NaN  04/27/2018  NATIONAL  FRUITS   BLUEBERRIES      NaN     Yes          NaN      4.4 oz package               528                4.02        NaN         NaN             NaN
10     NaN  04/27/2018  NATIONAL  FRUITS   BLUEBERRIES      NaN     Yes          NaN        6 oz package              2906                3.91        NaN         NaN             NaN
11     NaN  04/27/2018  NATIONAL  FRUITS    CANTALOUPS      NaN     NaN          NaN                each              9206                2.07        NaN         NaN             NaN
12     NaN  04/27/2018  NATIONAL  FRUITS    CANTALOUPS      NaN     NaN          NaN           per pound               633                0.50        NaN         NaN             NaN
13     NaN  04/27/2018  NATIONAL  FRUITS    CANTALOUPS      NaN     Yes          NaN                each                17                3.99        NaN         NaN             NaN
14     NaN  04/27/2018  NATIONAL  FRUITS   CLEMENTINES      NaN     NaN          NaN            2 lb bag              1083                3.83        NaN         NaN             NaN
15     NaN  04/27/2018  NATIONAL  FRUITS   CLEMENTINES      NaN     NaN          NaN            3 lb bag              1892                4.85        NaN         NaN             NaN
16     NaN  04/27/2018  NATIONAL  FRUITS   CLEMENTINES      NaN     NaN          NaN        5 lb package               110                4.99        NaN         NaN             NaN
17     NaN  04/27/2018  NATIONAL  FRUITS     HONEYDEWS      NaN     NaN          NaN                each              2360                2.90        NaN         NaN             NaN
18     NaN  04/27/2018  NATIONAL  FRUITS     HONEYDEWS      NaN     NaN          NaN           per pound               194                0.73        NaN         NaN             NaN
19     NaN  04/27/2018  NATIONAL  FRUITS     HONEYDEWS      NaN     Yes          NaN           per pound                39                0.99        NaN         NaN             NaN
20     NaN  04/27/2018  NATIONAL  FRUITS        LEMONS      NaN     NaN          NaN            2 lb bag               108                3.03        NaN         NaN             NaN
21     NaN  04/27/2018  NATIONAL  FRUITS        LEMONS      NaN     NaN          NaN                each              1858                0.57        NaN         NaN             NaN
22     NaN  04/27/2018  NATIONAL  FRUITS        LEMONS      NaN     NaN          NaN           per pound                26                0.99        NaN         NaN             NaN
23     NaN  04/27/2018  NATIONAL  FRUITS        LEMONS      NaN     Yes          NaN            2 lb bag                90                4.56        NaN         NaN             NaN
24     NaN  04/27/2018  NATIONAL  FRUITS        LEMONS      NaN     Yes          NaN                each               266                0.89        NaN         NaN             NaN
25     NaN  04/27/2018  NATIONAL  FRUITS         LIMES      NaN     NaN          NaN                each               966                0.35        NaN         NaN             NaN
26     NaN  04/27/2018  NATIONAL  FRUITS         LIMES      NaN     NaN          NaN           per pound               140                0.88        NaN         NaN             NaN
27     NaN  04/27/2018  NATIONAL  FRUITS         LIMES      NaN     Yes          NaN                each                70                0.79        NaN         NaN             NaN
28     NaN  04/27/2018  NATIONAL  FRUITS       MANGOES      NaN     NaN          NaN                each              7605                0.92        NaN         NaN             NaN
29     NaN  04/27/2018  NATIONAL  FRUITS       MANGOES      NaN     NaN          NaN           per pound                67                3.16        NaN         NaN             NaN
30     NaN  04/27/2018  NATIONAL  FRUITS       MANGOES      NaN     Yes          NaN                each              1664                1.31        NaN         NaN             NaN
31     NaN  04/27/2018  NATIONAL  FRUITS    PINEAPPLES      NaN     NaN          NaN                each             10297                2.14        NaN         NaN             NaN
32     NaN  04/27/2018  NATIONAL  FRUITS    PINEAPPLES      NaN     NaN          NaN           per pound               740                0.64        NaN         NaN             NaN
33     NaN  04/27/2018  NATIONAL  FRUITS    PINEAPPLES      NaN     Yes          NaN                each               248                2.68        NaN         NaN             NaN
34     NaN  04/27/2018  NATIONAL  FRUITS    PINEAPPLES      NaN     Yes          NaN           per pound               393                1.05        NaN         NaN             NaN
35     NaN  04/27/2018  NATIONAL  FRUITS         PLUMS      NaN     NaN          NaN           per pound               280                1.72        NaN         NaN             NaN
36     NaN  04/27/2018  NATIONAL  FRUITS  POMEGRANATES      NaN     NaN          NaN                each               285                3.04        NaN         NaN             NaN
37     NaN  04/27/2018  NATIONAL  FRUITS  STRAWBERRIES      NaN     NaN          NaN        1 lb package             14569                2.44        NaN         NaN             NaN
38     NaN  04/27/2018  NATIONAL  FRUITS  STRAWBERRIES      NaN     NaN          NaN        2 lb package              1588                3.32        NaN         NaN             NaN
39     NaN  04/27/2018  NATIONAL  FRUITS  STRAWBERRIES      NaN     Yes          NaN        1 lb package              4296                3.71        NaN         NaN             NaN
40     NaN  04/27/2018  NATIONAL  FRUITS  STRAWBERRIES      NaN     Yes          NaN        2 lb package               139                5.98        NaN         NaN             NaN
41     NaN  04/27/2018  NATIONAL  FRUITS      TANGELOS      NaN     NaN          NaN            3 lb bag               192                5.98        NaN         NaN             NaN
42     NaN  04/27/2018  NATIONAL  FRUITS      TANGELOS      NaN     NaN          NaN                each                81                1.42        NaN         NaN             NaN
43     NaN  04/27/2018  NATIONAL  FRUITS      TANGELOS      NaN     NaN          NaN           per pound                14                1.25        NaN         NaN             NaN
44     NaN  04/27/2018  NATIONAL  FRUITS    TANGERINES      NaN     NaN          NaN            2 lb bag                88                2.90        NaN         NaN             NaN
45     NaN  04/27/2018  NATIONAL  FRUITS    TANGERINES      NaN     NaN          NaN            3 lb bag              1022                4.99        NaN         NaN             NaN
46     NaN  04/27/2018  NATIONAL  FRUITS    TANGERINES      NaN     NaN          NaN        5 lb package                11                6.99        NaN         NaN             NaN
47     NaN  04/27/2018  NATIONAL  FRUITS    TANGERINES      NaN     NaN          NaN           per pound               385                1.69        NaN         NaN             NaN
48     NaN  04/27/2018  NATIONAL  FRUITS    TANGERINES      NaN     Yes          NaN            2 lb bag               612                3.99        NaN         NaN             NaN
49     NaN  04/27/2018  NATIONAL  FRUITS    TANGERINES      NaN     Yes          NaN                each                28                1.25        NaN         NaN             NaN
```